# local host 5000 is not working in windows , but all the container is running in windows

Tags: powershell, docker, flask, window

1.docker build in the powershell

2.when i execute this command

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up  --force-recreate
```

the container is up running and no error but the localhost is not working

```
PS C:\Users\ docker-compose run app
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Comment: Please post your compose file. It's possible you didn't map container port to host port or didn't expose it.

Comment: i have maped the port to host no issue on that  ,  i resolved the issue , the problem is the power shell will not work with docker container , then same thing i was done with the git bash the port is working fine .